# How to host 4000+ Images for download

Tags: media, files

I have around 4300 images that I want to share with around 100 people. In total they are 15gb. I have a Drupal 7 webserver with unlimited traffic and enough free storage to upload them on but I don't know an elegant / simple solution to distribute them.

The only simple approach I can think of, is zipping a few images together in a way I would get 15x 1gb files and just send everyone a link to these 15 files.. but that would be pretty lame wouldn't it? It would also be problematic for people with instable / slow internet because they might not be able to download 1gb large files without interruptions.

Is there any good solution? The people who need to recieve the images are "standard user" so it has to be a simple solution. I thought of a flash app of some sort which would run in the browser and download all the images one file at a time but I don't know if something like that exists.

I don't think it should be database related, because the Images are not getting used elsewhere on the site.. I would love to just upload them into a folder and having some easy way for the clients to download it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 15GB of data, and you need to give a complete copy of this 15GB to 100 people?  If so, I would consider mailing a couple DVDs or seeding a torrent instead of using Drupal.

Comment: well.. yes i have 15GB of data i have to distribute to ~100 people. I considered DVDs but that would be around 400 disks I would have to write, which I don't have the time to. I don't like the idea of having people download aditional software to get some pictures, so torrent is no option. So there isn't a simple solution? :( I guess I will split them up in parts and distribute the links then.

Comment: I don't think it's drupal related issue..

Comment: @RajeevK As long as the solution doesn't change when replacing Drupal with, for example, Joomla or WordPress, then the question is not specific for Drupal.

Comment: stack overflow you are saying?.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034503/how-to-host-4000-images-for-download :/ i think i will figure something out with a small batch file and wget/curl.. thanks for the help anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

I would think rsync would be a bit better suited to this task, I would simply place all the files on a server for example in

```
/srv/photoshare
```

Create a group to share to:

```
groupadd photoshare
```

Then create user for each person in the group, and add them to that group:

```
useradd -G photoshare photouser1
```

Or add an existing user to the group

```
gpasswd -a photouser2 photoshare
```

then each person can sync to local directory with this command:

```
rsync -ave ssh photouser1@HOSTNAME:/srv/photoshare ./
```

alternatively, if you don't have shell access, you can just stick them all in a subdomain, turn on directory indexing with an .htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes
```

and use wget:

```
wget -m www.example.com
```

also you could try a gallery plugin, but from your request I think that is not what you want.

Comment: I like your approach, but it would require each person to download additional software / use command line commands which I don't think they want to mess with.

Comment: yes, users can be such babies when it comes to command lines, this could always be alleviated by wrapping the commands in a perl or python app that could be double-clickable, but I think the dropbox alternatives would be a bit more elegant

Answer (score 1):

also you might want to try dropbox or one of it's alternatives:

https://owncloud.com/

http://sparkleshare.org/

http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html

http://seafile.com/en/home/

Comment: I thought about that, but I figured the download speeds would be pretty bad. Sometimes I use dropbox to share small files, but I only get download rates of ~50kbps. Are any of the other hosters better for free users? I don't really want to pay anything for it and since I have a webserver I figured I could use that aswell.

Comment: the owncloud and other alternatives speeds should be entirely based upon your hosts upload speeds,  with the exception of the bittorrent sync, I believe the users would start sharing with each other using this method greatly increasing the 'bandwidth' seen by end users, this might be a good option to pursue, I'm certainly going to toy with it today

Comment: owncloud looks intresting - I will look into it. The Bittorrent solution requires the users to download a software which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at all four again, I believe they all require the download of a client as well, at least if a user wants to take advantage of download resuming, and continual syncing for future changes.  I am doing some team collaboration myself and all of these look to be very promising.  If you really want to it to be clientless, I'll post a more gruesome answer

Comment: straight browser, ok ugly cross your fingers and pray method, merely zip the files up and stick them in a directory somewhere accessible to the 15 people:

http://www.example.com/share/giant.zip

but at 15 gigs I think you'll run into lots of downloads failing after so long, IF the server will even allow downloads that big, in which case you'll need to use zipsplit or p7zip, etc to split the files down to smaller chunks, however, I think this is ugly and it brings me back to 1998, times have changed.

Comment: yeah I kinda want to avoid having a gigantic zip file.. The files are never going to be changed, so having continuous sync is unneccessary. Are there any lightweight software solutions? I'm thinking something like: download a ready to use (no installation) program which downloads the images (should be easy to use, resumable downloads) and delete it afterwards no problem? That would be acceptable I guess. But I won't force the users to install anything. I feel something like it should exist as a flash app.. but I have no idea if it actually does :/

Answer (score 1):

Okay for a simple downloader with resuming nothing is going to beat wget, using either the gigantic zip file or the directory with indexes turned on method

But you say your users refuse to use a command line?  Probably windows users, so:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/winwget/

there is also a perl gui for multiplatform support:

http://www.martin-achern.de/wgetgui/

the -c option for wget will automatically resume, and the -m is a collection of options that will 'mirror' the link recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, and there is a drupal option apparently: the [Resumable Download](https://www.drupal.org/project/resumable_download) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Drupal does not support download resume , meaning that downloading large private files can be troublesome because if for any reason the download fails, there is no way to continue downloading from where it stopped and the whole file should be downloaded again.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Multi Part/Section file download
> - Resumable file download
> - Download speed limit support
> - Automatic client download abort detection